# Bluetooth won't be working in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I booted my `ASUS TUF Gaming F15 FX506LI_FX506LI` into ubuntu 20.04 a couple of days ago but when I try to connect my wireless headphone or even my smartphone Bluetooth it doesn't show any devices for pairing in ubuntu settings,

[system setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9KIs.png)

then I try to do some debugging but I was failed miserably. I was trying to download blueman-manager but when I run `blueman-manager` command in terminal it show me

```
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting

blueman-manager 17.01.37 ERROR Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.

blueman-manager 17.01.37 ERROR Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

following error.

Here are some debug log -

[dmesg](https://github.com/priyanshuSharma-WebDev/debug-info/blob/main/dmesg.txt)

[ispci -vv](https://github.com/priyanshuSharma-WebDev/debug-info/blob/main/lspci.txt)

and one more thing I'm completely noob in linux and computer hardware please help me in simple English!

Comment: ```systemctl enable bluetooth``` we'll try this , looks like daemon is not running :)

Comment: I run this command but the problem still remains the same. output ```Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth```

Comment: What is the brand of your bluetooth adapter intel or something else

Comment: I think it is MediaTek